chemfig: placing the starting atom at a coordinate in tikz
I have two molecules with the following code, but I want their first atoms to start at the same location. Any ideas?
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (first) at (0, 0) {
\chemfig{-=-=}
};

\setchemfig{bond style={blue}}
\node (second) at (0, 0) {
\chemfig{-[1]=[1]}
};

\end{tikzpicture}


chemfig always places the first atom of the molecule on the baseline. You need only to use the anchor=base west key:

(from tikz manual, section 71, Shape Library).
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=base west] (first) at (0, 0) {
    \chemfig{C-=-=}
  };

  \setchemfig{bond style={blue}}
  \node[anchor=base west] (second) at (0, 0) {%
    \chemfig{C-[1]=[1]}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Try this:
\chemfig{(-[1]=[1])-=-=}


